# SQL summary from two weeknum columns

Tags: sql

Is possible write a SQL Query to get the summary results below..?

Table preview:

```
UniqueID     StartWk     FinishWk
ID000001     2016|49     2016|49
ID000002     2016|49     2016|50
ID000003     2016|49     NULL
ID000004     2016|49     2016|50
ID000005     2016|49     2016|50
ID000006     2016|50     NULL
ID000007     2016|50     NULL
ID000008     2016|50     2016|50
ID000009     2016|50     2016|51
```

Summary output:

```
Week         Started     Finished
2016|49      5           1
2016|50      4           4
2016|51      0           1
```

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Use count(startWk) and count(FinishWk) for same year+week. After use GROUP BY clauses

Comment: Check [ask] for tips on getting the most out of StackOverflow.  In general, it's best to add some code that you have tried that doesn't work, as this is a Q&A site, not a code-for-me site.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach but I don't believe it's the most efficient.

First we need a set of all the weeks because you could have a finish week w/o a start or vice versa in your data.

Then we simply use a query to select the count for each weekly value.

```
SELECT A.week
    , (SELECT count(1) FROM table B WHERE B.StartWk = A.Week) as Started
    , (SELECT count(1) FROM table C WHERE C.FinishWk= A.Week) as Finished

FROM (SELECT startWk as Week FROM Table WHERE startWk is not null UNION 
      SELECT FinishWk as Week FROM Table WHERE FinishWk is not null
      ) A
```

This would likely be more efficient as it's able to get the counts once for each week instead of having to execute 2 queries for every week in the combined weeks.

```
SELECT A.Week, B.Started, C.Finished
FROM (SELECT startWk as Week FROM Table WHERE startWk is not null UNION 
      SELECT FinishWk as Week FROM Table WHERE FinishWk is not null) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT startWk, count(1) Started
           FROM TABLE
           GROUP BY StartWk) B
  ON A.Week = B.startWk
LEFT JOIN (SELECT FinishWk, count(1) Finished
           FROM TABLE
           GROUP BY FinishWk) C
  ON A.Week = C.FinishWk
```

Comment: I would change that: SELECT A.Week, ISNULL(B.Started, 0), ISNULL(C.Finished, 0) so it get rids of NULLs.

And add where: WHERE Week IS NOT NULL

Rest of that query is brilliant.

Comment: I think I agree with the `where week is not null` need to test the other...

Comment: not in MSSQL I was testing your query :) It ignores NULLs in counting column, so not adding null-row to count, but if there is nothing to count, it keeps null.

Comment: By eliminating the nulls in the initial union, the correlated query and the left joins (and counting before join) eliminate the need for the isNull/coalesce

Answer (score 1):

If your DBMS is ANSI compliant, below should work for you:

```
select
    coalesce(a.week, b.week) week,
    coalesce(a.cnt, 0) started,
    coalesce(b.cnt, 0) finished
from 
    (select startwk week, count(1) cnt from t where startwk is not null group by startwk) a
full outer join
(select finishwk week, count(1) cnt from t where finishwk is not null group by finishwk) b
on a.week = b.week
order by week;
```

Comment: No need.  You indicated DBMS must be ANSI compliant, mySQL must not be if it doesn't support full outer join. :P

Answer (score 0):

Using xQbert Query i am updating query like below.

```
SELECT 
    A.`Week`, 
    COALESCE(B.Started,0)Started, 
    COALESCE(C.Finished,0)Finished
FROM (SELECT StartWk as `Week` FROM my_table_name UNION 
      SELECT FinishWk as `Week` FROM my_table_name ) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT startWk, count(1) Started
           FROM my_table_name
           GROUP BY StartWk) B
  ON A.`Week` = B.StartWk
LEFT JOIN (SELECT FinishWk, count(1) Finished
           FROM my_table_name
           GROUP BY FinishWk) C
  ON A.`Week` = C.FinishWk
WHERE TRIM(A.`Week`) != ''
ORDER BY A.`Week`;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/ILJAX69950)

**Output:**

[image]